# JavaScript Math.min returns wrong value

Tags: javascript, arrays, min

I'm using [John Resig's function](http://ejohn.org/blog/fast-javascript-maxmin/) to find min value in an array but it returns somehow floored  value.
Here's a [demo](http://jsbin.com/izejop/3/) and here's the code.

```
 var arr = Math.min.apply(Math, [310127563311820800, 310127563190202368, 310127563110502401, 310127562443595776, 310127562326163457, 310127561751556097]);
document.write(arr);
```

Can you explain me what happens and why it's returning wrong(floored) value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't in finding the min but in using those numbers. You can't represent them as numbers in JavaScript as integers can only be completely kept between `-9007199254740992` and `+9007199254740992`.

It's because all numbers in JavaScript are double precision [IEEE754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) floats and the size of the mantissa is 53.

See more details in [ECMAScript specification on the number type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.5) :

> Note that all the positive and negative integers whose magnitude is no
>   greater than 253 are representable in the Number type (indeed, the
>   integer 0 has two representations, +0 and -0).

To deal with those numbers (and find their min), you need to use another representation than the native JavaScript number. Hopefully, there are many libraries dealing with big numbers, for example [bignum](https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum) (but you should google and pick the one you like).

Comment: Is there another way to find the min value in an array where the numbers exceed that interval?

Answer (score 1):

You will lose precision in javascript unless you make the input **strings** of digits.

If they are all positive integers you can sort them and return the lowest indexed element, remembering that a string with more  digits must be larger than one with fewer-

```
var input= ['310127563311820800', '310127563190202368', '310127563110502401',
'310127562443595776', '310127562326163457', '310127561751556097'];


var minim= input.slice(0).sort(function(a, b){
    if(a=== b) return 0;
    if(a.length!= b.length) return a.length-b.length;
    return a>b? 1:-1;  
})[0];

alert(minim);

/*  returned value: (String)
310127561751556097
*/
```

You can skip the slice(0) bit if you don't need to keep the original in its order.